# cual es el permiso para acceder al registro de llamadas en Xamrin.Android?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Estoy en las clases de funciones nativas y no se cual es el permiso para acceder al historial de llamadas de mi celular

Comment: Hola, Gaby.. aquí podrás encontrar los permisos que necesitas https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html?hl=es-419 y recuerda que desde Android Marshmallow necesitas preguntarle al usuario si te concede los permisos.